# How to find ID that occurs across multiple categories

Tags: oracle

hi I have a query called cte. I have to find IDs in this query that occur across multiple categories. Here are the fields available in my table:

| product_owner | product_ownerid | owner_location | owner_locationid | case_id | unique_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| red | 123 | texas | 321 | 12345 | 89076 |
| red | 123 | texas | 321 | 12345 | 89075 |
| blue | 456 | NY | 786 | 12678 | 90768 |
| blue | 456 | NY | 786 | 12678 | 90769 |
| red | 123 | texas | 321 | 12678 | 79072 |

in this case, 12678 exists for both red and blue category. I want to create a final table that looks like this:

| product_owner | product_ownerid | owner_location | owner_locationid | case_id | unique_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| blue | 456 | NY | 786 | 12678 | 90768 |
| blue | 456 | NY | 786 | 12678 | 90769 |
| red | 123 | texas | 321 | 12678 | 79072 |

I would really appreciate if someone could please help me figure out how I can achieve this. So far, this is what I have tried but it is not yielding the result that I want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
cte.product_owner, 
cte.product_ownerid,
cte.owner_location,
cte.owner_locationid, 
cte.Case_ID, 
cte.unique_id
FROM cte 
JOIN (SELECT Case_ID FROM cte
GROUP BY Case_ID
HAVING count (DISTINCT unique_id) >1) y
ON cte.Case_ID = y.Case_ID
ORDER BY cte.Case_Reference_ID
```

Comment: Why are you counting `DISTINCT unique_id` if your criteron is multiple categories (aptly named `product_owner`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count the distinct `product_ownerid` for each `case_id` and filter out the rows where the count is only 1:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(DISTINCT product_ownerid) OVER (PARTITION BY case_id)
           AS num_products
  FROM   cte t
)
WHERE  num_products > 1
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE cte (
  product_owner, product_ownerid, owner_location, owner_locationid, case_id, unique_id
) AS
SELECT 'red',  123, 'texas', 321, 12345, 89076 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'red',  123, 'texas', 321, 12345, 89075 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'blue', 456, 'NY',    786, 12678, 90768 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'blue', 456, 'NY',    786, 12678, 90769 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'red',  123, 'texas', 321, 12678, 79072 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | PRODUCT_OWNER | PRODUCT_OWNERID | OWNER_LOCATION | OWNER_LOCATIONID | CASE_ID | UNIQUE_ID | NUM_PRODUCTS |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | red | 123 | texas | 321 | 12678 | 79072 | 2 |
> | blue | 456 | NY | 786 | 12678 | 90769 | 2 |
> | blue | 456 | NY | 786 | 12678 | 90768 | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=fec0ab6ff8ad7a9f86e63b74b3e24d91)*